# Multiple animations within a relative view

Tags: android, animation, imageview, android-relativelayout

I am trying to animate a pointer around the screen in an android application.

I am using an imageview as the pointer inside a relative layout as follows:

```
    final RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    pointer =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pointer);
    pointer.animate().setDuration(2000);
```

I then want to move the pointer up 10 pixels every time I click a button:

```
    // ONCLICK LISTENER FOR LEFT BUTTON
            btnUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    //get positon of pointer
                     leftPoint = pointer.getLeft();
                     topPoint = pointer.getTop();


                    int xValue = container.getWidth() - pointer.getWidth();
                    int yValue = container.getHeight() - pointer.getHeight();
                    pointer.animate().x(leftPoint).y(topPoint-10);


                }
            });
```

This works the first time I click the button but will not move it any subsequent times. I have tried making the int points static but this did not help.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound counter-intuitive, but animating a view doesn't change its location.  Your code is demonstrating it.  When you do this line:

```
topPoint = pointer.getTop();
```

You get the same value every time.

You need to change pointer's position at the end of the animation.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8490244/793607) shows how someone else has done it.

**Other Considerations**

- You could use object animator, if you are only targeting SDK 11 and above.  [Here is a little intro](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/create-slick-transitions-with-androids-objectanimator-class/2052) to it.
- If you want to interrupt your animation, you can check its status, and find out its current y offset.  You can add that to the position of the view before starting the animation.  [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8358383/793607) an example.